# ComboBox Not Returned the selectedItem

Tags: c#, combobox

i have bounded DataSource to a combox box and then set this Code

```
Combox1.ValueMember = "CapacityID";
Combox1.DisplayMember = "Capacitys";
```

it show Data with no problem , but when i want gain selectedtext it returned me "" and using selectedItem , return name of combo box !
selectedvalue return correct data .

```
Combox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); //return "Combox1"
Combox1.SelectedValue.ToString(); //Work Correctly
Combox1.SelectedText.ToString(); // return ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBox.Text.Tostring() returned selected text and solved my problem

```
 String status = "The status of my combobox is " + comboBoxTest.Text
```

SelectedText property from MSDN

```
Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.
```

while Text property from MSDN

```
Gets or sets the text associated with this control.
```

Answer (score 1):

`Combox1.SelectedItem` retunrs you selected ListItem object not text value of selected item

its should be like  :

```
ListItem li = Combox1.SelectedItem;
```

or

```
Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + selectedItem.ToString() );
```

From MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx

---

`Combox1.SelectedText` - Check Msdn for this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx

**FROM MSdn why its return empty string** - if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, So What Is the Solution ?

Comment: @Moslem7026 - for the first one its object type or listitem that you can read from msdn doc..for second one same thing you can check msdn there is in some situation it get blank..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Combox1.SelectedItem.Text // To get SelectedText
Combox1.SelectedItem.Value // To get SelectedValue
```

Instead of

```
Combox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Comment: I have No Text in Combox1.SelectedItem namespace ! Why ?!

Answer (score 0):

So altough, your question is not really gramatically clear, to get the calue of your selected item always use

```
Combox1.SelectedValue
```

Why?

Because:

```
Combox1.SelectedItem
```

returns a string that represents the currently selected text in the combo box. **If DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList, the return value is an empty string ("").**

Comment: selected value works and return selected value , i have problem in selected text.

Comment: i don't really understand what you need, perhaps you need to first express clearly what you want.

Comment: my combo box has two part , selected value and selected text , selected value work correctly but selected text return ""

Comment: but my DropDownStyle has not been set to DropDownList, its DropDown